# System.load('native library') not working on applet from browser

Tags: java, applet, rxtx

I am using Following code in my applet, which is executing jar file from local system. its running properly on my IDE. when i run this applet from the browser(java enabled FireFox) it doesn't run without any exception. After some R&D i found that the native library(RXTX) is not loading when i am using browser.How can i resolve this?

**Applet Code which is executing local JAR file**

String command = "java -jar path/MyJar.jar";

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

**MyJar code which one is loading native library**

```
static{
    try{

        System.load(path+"\\rxtxSerial.dll");

        System.setProperty("java.library.path", path);

        Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");

        fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);

        fieldSysPath.set(null, null);

        System.loadLibrary("rxtxSerial");

        }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Browsers are sandboxed so you can't access system resources, only the sandbox resources. I have no idea if the typical browser sandbox tunnels the serial ports. Running DLLs is impossible anyway since you don't know if the user has Linux or otherwise.

Comment: if i can access jarFile through applet , so why i can not access RXTX.dll ?